# How to write custom reduction function with 0 and 2-ary cases

Tags: clojure

The following example in `clojure` calls the nullary and binary cases of `+` in various ways:

```
(println 101 (+)) ; fine
(println 102 (+ (+) 4)) ; fine

(println 103 (reduce + (+) (range 4))) ; fine
(println 104 (reduce + (range 4))) ; fine
```

I tried replacing `+` with `mean-reducer` as described in [this blog post (warning: no https)](http://ignaciothayer.com/post/Transducers-Are-Fundamental/).

I changed the `mean-reducer` function to explicitly expose its identity element `{:sum 0 :count 0}` when invoked with no arguments.

This works fine for the simple cases *leading up to* `(reduce mean-reducer (range 4))`, but falls over for `(reduce mean-reducer (range 4))` itself.

```
(defn mean-reducer
  ([] {:sum 0 :count 0})
  ([memo x]
         {
             :sum (+ x (memo :sum))
             :count (inc (memo :count))
         }))

(println 201 (mean-reducer)) ; fine
(println 202 (mean-reducer (mean-reducer) 4)) ; fine

(println 203 (reduce mean-reducer (mean-reducer) (range 4))) ; fine
;; (println 204 (reduce mean-reducer (range 4))) ; bad
```

runs and produces this with the last line commented.

```
% clojure mean_reducer.clj
201 {:sum 0, :count 0}
202 {:sum 4, :count 1}
203 {:sum 6, :count 4}
```

The error message and stack trace associated with the failed call to `(reduce mean-reducer (range 4))` looks like this:

```
(~/clojure/mean_reducer.clj:12:62).
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7647)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:7573)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invokeStatic(main.clj:452)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invokeStatic(main.clj:512)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:507)
    at clojure.main$main.invokeStatic(main.clj:598)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:561)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:705)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; clojure.lang.IFn is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at user$mean_reducer.invokeStatic(mean_reducer.clj:5)
    at user$mean_reducer.invoke(mean_reducer.clj:1)
    at clojure.lang.LongRange.reduce(LongRange.java:222)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6823)
    at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6810)
    at user$eval143.invokeStatic(mean_reducer.clj:13)
    at user$eval143.invoke(mean_reducer.clj:13)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:7176)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:7635)
    ... 9 more
```

I *think* this means that somehow the lines are getting crossed and an element of `(range 4)` is being bound to `memo`, but I'm not sure why this would happen given that the case with an explicit initial element succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass no *initial value* to `reduce` the 2-arity version of `mean-reducer` is invoked with the first two elements of the range i.e. `(mean-reducer 0 1)`. From `reduce` docs:

> If val is not supplied, returns the result of applying f to the first 2 items in coll, then applying f to that result and the 3rd item, etc.

You'll need to supply an *initial value* to `reduce` if you want to use `mean-reducer` (and its 0-arity won't be used). `reduce` has two different "contracts" for its 2-arity reducing function depending on whether an initial value is specified.

### clojure.core.reducers

[`clojure.core.reducers/reduce`](https://clojure.org/reference/reducers#_reduce_and_fold) has exactly the behavior you want when no initial value is supplied:

> When init is not provided, (f) is used.

```
(r/reduce mean-reducer (range 4))
=> {:sum 6, :count 4}
```